# how to prepare a list of files for building rpm from RPM spec file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am working in a big module where we build several RPMs from a single vob . We have a seperate spec file for each module and the list of files to be required for each module is specified in the RPM SPEC file.

I can't blindly build a tar containing libraries of all modules which will be of 7 GB size (but, anyway, I need 30 out of 10000 files for any particular module).

I need to build a tar of required files, which is specified under %files section of each SPEC.

Is it possible to grep %files section from SPEC before **building .tar (before building RPM)**

I tried :

```
   rpm -ql --specfile module1.spec
   (contains no files)

   rpm -ql --queryformat '%{NAME}: %{FILENAMES}\n' --specfile module1.spec
   Module1: (none)
   (contains no files)
```

But my %file section contains around 30 files.

What I planned is to extract files from the SPEC , prepare a file list , pass `tar -cvf module1.tar -T module_file_list_1` and include in the SPEC as `SOURCE : /dir_1/module1.tar`

Comment: I'm missing something here. Why do you need to build a tar file?

Comment: Why do you have them in separate `spec` files? At work, I have one source spec file that generates over 70 RPMs (long, long story). You can use `-n` (IIRC) in package names if you won't want them to inherit the base package name as a prefix.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco : Are using single spec file for building RPM for 70 **different independent modules** ?? If so, can u pls show me with tutorial ?

Comment: Yes, subpackages, as noted.